# What is the controller key "selection" and how does it get its default state?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings, nsobjectcontroller

I'm working on an app right now that needs to use bindings as glue code from the controller. I found this tutorial which bound an `NSStepper` and `NSTextField` to a model and it works fine. The problem is that I need to do this programmatically, but it's a bit confusing.

[Here's the tutorial](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/059-NSStepper-NSTextField.pl).

What I've done in my controller class:

```
[self    bind:@"contentObject" 
     toObject:_model 
  withKeyPath:@"self" 
      options:nil];
```

where `_model` is my model. But then, if I do this:

```
[someKVCObject bind:@"value" 
           toObject:self 
        withKeyPath:@"selection.somethingInMyModel" 
            options:nil];
```

It doesn't work as I expect.

Can someone explain to me like I'm five what the `selection` part is for an `NSObjectController` and how I can make it work like the tutorial does so that it references the model object?

Comment: What does "doesn't work as expected" mean? What are your expectations, and what are the actual results?

Comment: I mean that it isn't actually changing the value of "somethingInMyModel" when "value" is changed.